# When i am trying to run the javascript i am finding some warnings,how to overcome that

Tags: javascript, xcode

When i am trying to run the javascript in the xcode,i am finding some warnings,

The following are the warnings,

```
[WARN]warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/js/binofo.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
[WARN]warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/js/excanvas.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
[WARN]warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/js/jqtouch.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
[WARN]warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/js/jqtouch.min.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
[WARN]warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/js/jqtouch.transitions.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
[WARN]warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
[WARN]warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/js/jquery-1.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
[WARN]warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/js/jquery.1.3.2.min.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
[WARN]warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/js/jquery.jqChart.min.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
[WARN]warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/js/jquery.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
[WARN]warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/js/jquery.sparkline.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
[WARN]warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/js/urchin.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add js file to my xcode project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017937/how-to-add-js-file-to-my-xcode-project)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430786/warning-no-rule-to-process-javascript-for-architecture-armv7/21924281#21924281

Answer (score 6):

Are you adding those .js files to www? or Plugins?
If www - Open your project in finder , project --> www --> add all .js files.
Now open your project in xcode and check www, it should expand with all .js files.

If Plugins --When you add the JavaScript file, Xcode detects that the file is a source code file, assumes you want to compile it and automatically adds it to the Compile Sources build phase.

To stop Xcode trying to compile it and make it copy the file instead, expand your target in the Groups and Files list, remove the JavaScript file from the Compile Sources build phase and add it to the Copy Bundle Resources build phase.

It worked for me.