# Reading a Javascript file in a Bundle to String Xcode IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, string, bundle

I have tried this in a variety of ways and yet it never pops out my file as a string.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Perhaps a fresh set of eyes can get it.

```
static NSString *JSParse;


JSParse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nameFinder" ofType:@"js" ] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nameFinder" ofType:@"js"];
NSLog(filepath);
if (filepath)
{
    NSString *someJscript = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
    NSLog(someJscript);
}
NSLog(@"StartParse");
NSLog(JSParse);
NSLog(@"End Parse");
```

The end goal is to use javascript to parse HTML from a website that isn't mine and yes it sucks.  (Parsing although my code is suspect too at this point);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2018644/526547

You don't need to change your .js to .txt if you use this method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity.  Whats the odds you can help me with my mutable array  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587818/addobjectsfromarray-not-copying-into-global-nsmutablearray

Answer (score 0):

The Reason for this has something to do with it being a JS file extension.  Changing it to a txt file invariably fixes the problem.  I'm not sure why this is so but i'm assuming it's some compilation issues.