# addObjectsFromArray: not copying into global NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsarray

So here is a partial sample of the relevant code.

```
static NSMutableArray *radioInputArray;
static NSMutableArray *buttonsArray;


- (IBAction)lookForRadioButtons:(id)sender {
    //  NSLog(@"Testing");
    NSError *error;
    NSString *radiostr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"getRadios" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error: &error] ;
    if (radiostr == nil)
    {
        NSLog (@"Error! %@", error);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",radiostr);
        NSString *radiotxt=  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:radiostr];
        NSLog(@"%@", radiotxt);
        NSArray *myRadios = [radiotxt componentsSeparatedByString:@"::"];
        [radioInputArray addObjectsFromArray:myRadios];
        NSLog(@"%d", myRadios.count);
        NSLog(@"Number of buttons in global radio array %d", radioInputArray.count);
        NSLog(@"%d", scrollViewer.subviews.count);
    }
}
```

So it throws no exceptions and seems to work properly except after `addObjectsFromArray:`, my count in the global `NSMutableArray` is 0 (the count in the myRadios = 56). I am pretty sure they should be equal at this point but are not. I have declared my `NSMutableArray` up near the top so that it can be globally accessed.  Am I missing something such as allocating and initializing this?  Does it not do that automatically like in C#?  Again, this is my first foray into the Objective-C world from Windows programming so please be gentle yet feel free to be critical.

Comment: It's a hell of a gotchya.  Just as you say it APPARENTLY WORKS, there's no error etc, in that situation!  Horrific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two global arrays are not initialized.

The lines

```
static NSMutableArray *radioInputArray;
static NSMutableArray *buttonsArray;
```

just define the two variables as pointers to `NSMutableArray`, so you need to get them to point at an actual instance of the class `NSMutableArray`.

Somewhere in your initialization code, or through an accessor (best if a class method), you should set the variables to an empty, newly allocated `NSMutableArray`.

Here is a way to do it:

```
+ (NSMutableArray*)radioInputArray
{
    if (!radioInputArray) {
        radioInputArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    }

    return radioInputArray;
}
```

Then use the accessor in your code instead of the global variable.

Comment: Right I keep getting an error that receiver type MutableArray does not declare a method with selector alloc.

Comment: How stupid of me! It should be `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` Code changed in answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if your `radioInputArray` is `nil`,
you didn't initialize the array

you need to add

```
[[radioInputArray alloc] init];
```

before you do anything with `radioInputArray`

Comment: Nothin.  Went so far as to do the following in my header.  

    property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *radioInputArray;

Then placed the 

    synthesize radioInputArray;

Inside my .m file and still no love although it shows no build errors when I still get a 56 for my original array and a 0 for my radioInputArray.  I have removed the at symbol as it wishes to notify people

Answer (score 0):

Good place for initialising object is "init" method in Global class

Ex.

```
-(id)init
{
    if (self=[super init]) {

        self.globalAllArtworkArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.globalCollectionArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.globalLookbookArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }
    return self;

}

+(ASNGlobalClass *)shareManager
{
    static ASNGlobalClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];

    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```