# React Native XCode js files in tabs

Tags: xcode, react-native

I' m searching for a solution to show all my js-files of my react native project in tabs in xcode. The normal way (single click on files in navigator) is not working because the js-files are not shown in the navigator.

Thanks for help

Comment: Well, I just started to play around with React Native and I got the same issue. Now I open them from finder ;) For sure it has to be some setting issue. Did you look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017937/how-to-add-js-file-to-my-xcode-project

Nothing worked for me there, I can't imagine we are the only 2 souls having this issue, it is funny nothing is mentioned about it in the React Native page.

Comment: Why would you want this? The whole point of React Native is that you build your app separately and then have it packaged?

Comment: @ Kolors: Don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. If you have opened a js file with xcode in seperate window, go to "view" -> "show tab bar". Also activate "show tabbar" in the xcode main window. Now you can drag the js file in the xcode main window. Important: drag the js file by clicking in the tabbar and drop it in the main window's tabbar.